# WIRIS plugin for CKeditor working locally but not online

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor

I am working on a project named online examination application. For that i have used CK Editor along with WIRIS plugin to insert mathematical symbols and other special characters. It is working on my local machine but after uploading online instead of symbols I am getting this:

> «math xmlns=¨http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML¨»«mroot»«mrow/»«mrow/»«/mroot»«/math»

Comment: Does anyone has any replies   ??

Answer (score 1):

Please, locate in the file `plugin.js` the line:

```
var _wrs_conf_saveMode = 'tags'; // This value can be 'tags', 'xml' or 'safeXml'
```

and set back to:

- `tags` if you want formulas to be images (that is the default)
- `xml` if you want formulas to be rendered from MathML by some modern browsers

Feel free to ask `support at wiris.com` for more help.